# Header Size Not Changing

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have tried increasing the header size in the html, css and the theme options in the Wordpress dashboard but to no avail. Any idea why it's not working or where else I can possibly change it? I'll post the code from the theme here. Thanks!

HTML:

```
h1 { font-size:<?php echo $of_option[$prefix.'fontsize_h1']['size'] ?>; }
```

CSS:

```
h1{ font-size:25px; line-height:1em; }
```

Under the theme options in Wordpress it says that the size for Header 1 is 35px.

Comment: Wait... it looks very incomplete. Can you paste everything that's necessary to https://jsfiddle.net/ and post link here?

Comment: Those are the only codes I could find for Header 1... What else should there be? I'm pretty new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess from this is that styles that you define in CSS are overriden by generated PHP code. I would try to do something like that although it's hacky:

```
h1 { 
    font-size:25px !important; 
    line-height:1em !important; 
}
```

Comment: That might have worked but that's just a quick fix. Please paste full code I can recommend you better solution then.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I'm not sure what else you're looking for... this was all I could find for the HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

I realized that "font-size" within the header does not change the font size, in contrast to (for example) "color" within the header which actually changes the color:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 60px; color: #800080">This is my title (in which I obtain the color I want, but not the font size I want)</h1>
```

However, if you put the "font-size" specification in "span" and sandwich the header within "span", that does the trick:

```
<span style="font-size: 60px"><h1 style="text-align: center; color: #800080">This is my title (in which I obtain the color I want and also the font size I want)</h1></span>
```